# How many names are provided for Allah in Quran and Hadith?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, dua, asma-ul-husna

When there are already 1000 questions are the islam.StackExchange, I found it interesting to ask the question 1001 about 1001 names of Allah:

There is a Du'a narrated from Imam Ali-ibn-Hussain from prophet Muhammad (PBUH) called [Joushan Kabir Dua (this links contain Du'a in Arabic, English and Persian)](http://www.duas.org/downloads/JoshanKabir.pdf) that is 100 parts, each containing 10 beautiful names of Allah. Also part 55 contains 11 names, so the total names of Allah in this Du'a will be 1001. I found calling Allah by 1001 names not only an very good way to ask him my needs - specially in Qadr nights, but also a excellent way to think and learn better about my Lord.

So my question is: How many names are provided for Allah (Asma-ul-Husna) in Hadith or Sunnah? Is there any name of Allah missing from this great Du'a, or is there any other source with more names of Allah? If not, maybe we can consider these 1001 names are all the names Muslims know about Allah.

Comment: it is very good...Acorrding to me their are ninty-nine names of Allah................

Comment: no one knows how many names of Allah there are but Allah alone - some sholars have different lists of these ninety names but i think you should look for the evidence for these names. And to limit a number to Allah's names is wrong simply because we dont know

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of supposed names of Allah in the Haidth, but this list is inauthentic and hence should not be listened to.  The scholars who reject this list (in the hadith) as inauthentic are, at-Tirmidhi, al-Baihaqi, ibn Hazm, al-Dawudi, ibn Taymiya, ibn Katheer, ibn Hajr, al-Juwaini, ibn Baz, al-Albani, ibn Uthaimin and Abdul Qadir al-Arnaut.

> لِلَّهِ تِسْعَةٌ وَتِسْعُونَ اسْمًا، مِائَةٌ إِلاَّ وَاحِدًا، لاَ
>   يَحْفَظُهَا أَحَدٌ إِلاَّ دَخَلَ الْجَنَّةَ، وَهْوَ وَتْرٌ يُحِبُّ
>   الْوَتْرَ
>
> Allah has ninety-nine Names, one hundred minus one, and whoever
>   believes in their meanings and acts accordingly, will enter Paradise;
>   and Allah is witr (one) and loves 'the witr'
>
> [Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/105)

There are ninety-nine names mentioned in the Quran, and in authentic Ahadith, anything other than these names are weak or fabricated.

Source: [Muttaqun Online](http://muttaqun.com/99names.html) To see the ninety-nine names in the link, scroll down.

Comment: What are that 99 names?

Comment: @Ali I updated my question.  Go to the link and scroll down.

Comment: Thanks for the link - though it's called weak on the same page. I have seen similar Hadith in Sunnah.com. One possibility is that these Hadith do not limit the names of Allah only to these 99 names, these 99 names are the names that having them is told to enter paradise, not the whole set maybe

Comment: I just want to add that the 99 names that we all have learned are debatable.